# Not including 'bold' or 'italic' Google font and it seems to work ok if I use them

Tags: css

When I include a Google font in my website and I just include the Normal 400 weight, I am still being able to use the bold, italic, etc weight although it hasn't been really included.

This is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9nYZb/

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

vs.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The browser will emulate the bold and italic fonts by simply making the standard font thicker or slanted.

If you compare the two, you will see that the one with the bold and italic fonts included looks better.

[image]

Comment: AKA "faux bold" and "faux italic".

Comment: The rendering of “faux bold” and “faux italic” varies by browser from poor to miserable. For example, on Safari, “faux bold” is in this case horrendously bold.

Comment: I see in the example even the 'a' in 'Jack' is absolutelly different.

Comment: Faux bold doesn't seem to be happening anymore in chrome, hmm...  It was handy :)

Comment: @Kevin: Where do you get that? When I try it in Chrome (44.0.2403.157) it still does that.